# Hook up to Build Action and check the number of warnings

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012

I want to create some sort of add-in to VS2012, that will check each build the number of warnings that there are in the code, and perform an action, depending on the amound of warnings.

I've searched the web for solutions, but couldn't find any direction.
Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: One possible solution, write a command line builder and search output for warnings.

Comment: Actually, my intends are to create this kind of add-in to my team, so without the use of external executable. I want it to be part of the visual studio compile progress.